# Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\pi(n) = \frac{n}{ln(n)}$, can't this be used to prove Legendre’s conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Legendre's conjecture states that for all $n$, there is a prime number between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$.

It has been proven that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\pi(n)  = \frac{n}{\ln(n)}$.

It can be proven that $\frac{(n+1)^2}{\ln((n+1)^2)} – \frac{n^2}{\ln(n^2)} > 1$ for all $n$.

At some large $n$, the difference between $\pi((n+1)^2) - \pi(n^2))$  and  $\frac{(n+1)^2}{\ln((n+1)^2)} – \frac{n^2}{\ln(n^2)}$ would be small enough to confirm Legendre's conjecture.

Comment: "It has been proven that $\pi(n)$ limit $n\to\infty = \frac{n}{\ln(n)}$." Better stated as $\pi(n)/(n/\ln n)\to 1.$

Answer (score 6):

No, because the error terms can hide a lot. You would really need to show that
$$
(1-\varepsilon)\frac{(n+1)^2}{\ln((n+1)^2)} – (1+\varepsilon)\frac{n^2}{\ln(n^2)} > 1
$$
when $n$ is large enough in terms of $\varepsilon$, but this is not true.

Here's a more concrete example: let $f(x)$ denote the number of integers up to $x$ whose last digit is either $1$, $2$, or $3$. It's easy to prove that $f(x)$ is asymptotic to $3x/10$ as $x\to\infty$. Note that $3(n+4)/10 - 3n/10 > 1$ for all $n$ . Does that show that there is always a number between $n$ and $n+4$ whose last digit equals $0$, $1$, or $2$?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree that the error has to be taken into consideration since n/ln(n) may differ significantly from $\pi(n)$. But unlike your example, the difference between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ increases dramatically as $n$ gets large. When $n=10,000$, the difference between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ is 20,001 and there are over 1000 primes between them. All we have to prove is that the error remains less than 1000 or some other constant. Is it that difficult?

Comment: It's very difficult. We can't even prove that the error for $\pi(x)$ stays less than $x^{0.999}$. And even assuming the Riemann hypothesis, we can't yet prove Lagrange's conjecture. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture